# add new Project to existing github Repo

Tags: git, github, commit, repository

I am developing a Client-Server application and I want to store both projects (Client and Server) on github the same github repo.
I am on macosx.
I created a local repository for the client side project with Eclipse git plugin and then I committed it to github. It worked fine.

Now I want to add to this Repo the server side project possibly inside a new subfolder. This part is developed on a different workspace than the client part. I tried to share the project using Eclipse, but it tells me there is no existing repo. I think this is because the two parts of the system are developed with different Eclipse IDEs.

I tried to create a new repo under the first one, but it became a great mess because github couldn't understand which was the master.
I am using the GitHub client application to manage commits to the remote repo.

Someone can help me?

Thanks

Comment: Is there any particular reason for not using two separate repositories?

Answer (score 2):

It probably doesn't answer your answer directly, but I think that this particular situation can be ruled with such feature of Git as [**submodules**](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules).

In this case you need to have two different repositories hosted somewhere, anyway. But with help of submodules you can tell Git that files of one repo should be located **inside the directory tree** of another one. Without causing the mess you described!

For example, assuming that you have your projects hosted as `github.com/user/Client` and `github.com/user/Server` repos. Go to the folder of `Client` repository and do the following:

```
git submodule add git@github.com:user/Server.git src/server
```

This will clone the repo with given address into the folder you specified (`src/server` in this example).

After that you have to commit changes. Although a lot of files were added, there will **not** be lots of changes in commit diff: there will be only a short record in special file saying that such repository now is a submodule. That is, files of `Server` not actually stored in `Client` repo, only the reference to them is stored. This is the power of git submodules.

Note that after that, when you clone your `Client` repo somewhere else, its submodule will not be fetched by default. You have to use `git submodule update --init` to initialize submodules.

Also note that the reference to `Server` submodule points to a specific revision of it. After you made some changes to `Server` repo you may want to go to `Client` repo, navigate to directory of submodule (`src/server` in this example) and do a simple `git pull` and commit changes in `Client` repo. Again, there will be no giant diff, only the new **reference** to submodule will be commited.

As an example of the repo with submodules you can check out my repo for Vim settings directory: it has many plugins inside its [bundle](https://github.com/NIA/dotvim/tree/master/bundle) folder and all of them are git submodules. GitHub shows them pretty well and allows easy one-click navigation to submodule repo if it is GitHub-hosted.

*P.S. If this all has nothing in common with what you want, and you simply want a folder `Server` to be added to repo `Client`, you can just copy `Server` to client **and** delete all traces of Git from `Server` directory (if there were some) by deleting `.git` inside it. Now you simply have one repo, commit all this lots of changes and go on. The drawback of this is complete loss of history of `Server` repo — it is not a big pain at the initial phase of project.*

Answer (score 0):

I think, that is not the way, git works. Git needs one root directory for a repository and all folders and files to commit must be inside of this one directory.

Answer (score 0):

Clone your existing repo using following command:

`git clone https://github.com/company/our_repo.git`

Manually take your project folder to the desired location i.e. trunk/bin

Now commit and then push in the repo using the commands:

```
git commit -m "message"
git push origin master
```